Different DTOs for object that contains id reference to another vs one that contains the full object?
In my Angular application I have a DTO for Workout, and this DTO can either contain an ExerciseSet object (with all of its data) or just contain the id of the ExerciseSet.
I want to extend a base DTO for Workout that contains only its information, and two DTOs, one for each of the described cases.
Is this a bad practice?
If not, is there a naming convention for such DTOs?
This is an example of what I'm picturing, and if something bothers you about the names I'd appreciate the feedback:
export interface WorkoutDto{
  id: string;
  // other fields inherent to Workout
}

// with full ExerciseSet data
export interface WorkoutWithExerciseSetDto extends WorkoutDto{
  exerciseSet: ExerciseSetDto;
}

// with only ExerciseSet id
export interface WorkoutWithExerciseSetIdDto extends WorkoutDto{
  exerciseSet: string;
}

Extra consideration: Sometimes I will have a WorkoutDto that contains sets that don't have an id.
I hope you can help me, and thanks in advance.

i don't see any reason why you should not stick to as it is, because it will be easy and efficient solution if you are not require to load full object reference but just the ID.
and for the required naming convention
i.e. using suffix of DTO with the 1st latter being capital same as in case of c#
for example   :
export class UserDTO {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
}


Thank you for the quick reply. What do you think about the names of the extended dtos? I think having the suffix WithExerciseSetDTO and WithExerciseSetIdDTO is a bit verbose, but I can't think of another way of naming them. Maybe I'm being too picky.

its ok as long as name describe its value and easy to understand by others then it's completely ok even if it looks bit longer. and yes i think you are being kind of picky which is completely normal in our community  of coder for many generation now :)

You're so kind in your replies, thank you for that. I have one more question, if Exercise also contains a nested object (which can also be a reference or the full object), should I add yet another Workout DTO or should I limit the depth of my DTOs to a certain degree?

i will suggest you to keep it simple but if any particular nested object is going to use frequently then nesting will we reasonable choice to implement.
